# How to find and remove the tracking codes running in my wordpress site?

Tags: google-analytics

In one of my old websites I inserted GTM and GA tracking codes. Now when I run my website 'BathindaHelper.com' in G Chrome, its Tag extension shows 3 tags are running (2 for GTM and one for GA). 
But when I check my wordpress website's backend, I don't find the code inserted in the theme 'header.php' or 'footer.php'. 
I also deleted any plugins like 'Insert Headers & Footers' or similar.

How can I find and remove those tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to a default theme like Twenty Twenty. If the tags are still running, you'll know for sure they're coming from a plugin. And if they're not running, you'll know the tags are somewhere in the theme.

(It's highly recommended to disable editing the theme directly in wp-admin. It is safer to FTP in and upload/download the files, in case any issues arise, so you can easily revert changes. This also makes it easier to search through the files - many editors have a "find in files" search feature so you could look for your specific tracking code, i.e. search for your GA UA- number.)

Comment: Can I assume that tags can only exist in one of 3 ways: Thru theme editing, thru plugin insertion, and thru direct editing of the code. And if I never edited the theme (or changing themes didn't eliminate the code running) and I never directly edited the code, can I assume that it was inserted by some plugin only (no other way possible). 
And if it was inserted by some plugin (I only installed reputed 2-3 plugins), will removing the plugin can achieve the aim, or its required to edit the plugin settings before its removal to remove the insertions it had made?

Comment: In theory, code can run from a theme, from a plugin, or from someone editing Core (whether that's you or a hacker, for instance). To verify it's coming from a plugin, follow the suggestions and switch to a default theme. If the tags are still there, they're most likely coming from a plugin, which yes, you can deactivate all plugins. Check whether the tags are still firing. If not, reactivate plugins one by one, testing each time until you determine which plugin is triggering it.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do that again. I'm saying 'again', because I already had switched the site theme from '2017' to '2020' and deactivated all plugins. But still chrome's tag extension was showing as if 3 were tags being running/firing. But I'll try to do the same once again, carefully. (And I never manually edited any theme or code). Thanks again.

Comment: You may want to verify all caches are cleared (your browser's cache and server cache) and also actually view the source to see if the tags are there in the code. I've noticed the Chrome extensions to preview tags aren't always showing the latest so it's safer to double-check the code itself.